# Diagonals with same characters - Python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

The program must accept a character matrix of size **RxC** as the input. The program must print the number of diagonals that parallel to the top-left to bottom-right diagonal and having the same characters in the matrix.

```
def lower_diagonals(row,matrix):
    # a list to store the lower diagonals
    # which are || to top left to bottom right
    d=[]
    # Iterating from the second row till the last row 
    for i in range(1,row):
        nop,dummy = [],0
        for j in range(i,row):
            try:
                nop.append(matrix[j][dummy])
            except:
                break
            dummy+=1
        d.append(nop)

    return d

def upper_diagonals(col,matrix):
    # a list to store the lower diagonals
    # which are || to top left to bottom right
    d=[]
    # Iterating from 1st column till the last column 
    for i in range(1,col):
        dum , nop = i,[]
        # Iterating till the last before row
        for j in range(row-1):
            try:
                nop.append(matrix[j][dum])
            except:
                break
            dum+=1
        d.append(nop)
    return d

def diagonals(matrix,row,col):
    return lower_diagonals(row,matrix) + upper_diagonals(col,matrix)

row,col = map(int,input().input().split())
matrix =[input().strip().split(' ') for i in range(row)]
new_matrix = diagonals(matrix,row,col)
t=0
for i in new_matrix:
    if len(list(set(i))) == 1 : t+=1
print(t)
```

> Example :

```
Input :
4 4
u m o a
h n a o
y h r w
b n h e

Output:
4
```

```
Input :
5 7 
G a # z U p 3
e G b # n U p
a e G m # e U
L l e g k # t
j L a e G s #

Output:
6
```

My code works perfect for all the above mentioned cases but it fails for the below case

```
Input :
2 100 
b h D k 2 D 9 I e Q # * B 5 H Z r q u n P C 4 a e K l 2 E p 6 R V v 0 d 8 x C F P M F C e m K H O y @ 0 I T r P 8 P N 9 Z 7 S J J P c L g x X f 5 1 o i Y V Y G Y 9 A E O 2 r 2 # S 8 z D 6 a q r i k r 
V o 4 T M m z p 6 G H D Y a 6 t O 7 # w y t 2 m A 1 a + 0 p t P D z 7 V N T x + I t 4 x x y 1 Q G M t M 0 v d G e u 4 b 8 m D @ I v D i T 1 u L f e 1 Y E Y q Y c A 8 P 2 q 2 A 8 y b u E 3 c 1 s M n X
Expected Output:
9
My Output:
100
```

Can anyone help me in structuring the logic for this case Thanks in advance

```
Note :
 2<=R,C<=100
 Time limit : 500ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i probably found a logic for my problem

```
r,c = map(int,input().strip().split())
mat = []
for i in range(r):
    l = list(map(str,input().strip().split()))
    mat.append(l[::-1])
count = 0
for i in range(r+c-1):
    l = []
    for row in range(r):
        for col in range(c):
            if row+col == i:
                l.append(mat[row][col])
    l = list(set(l))
    if len(l) == 1:
        count+=1
print(count)
```